# Are there solutions for this functional equation?

Tags: probability-distributions, functional-equations

The distribution $g(x)$ has the following properties:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g'(x)f(x)dx=f(\pi g(0)-1/2)-f(\pi g(0)+1/2)$$

for any analytic $f(x)$.

How can I find $g(x)$?

Comment: Maybe this $g(x)=\theta(x+1/2)-\theta(x-1/2)$, where $\theta$ is unit step function?

Comment: @Nemo for f(x)=x the left hand side gives 2, the right hand side gives -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your equation extends to smooth test functions, this is just $g'=\delta_{\pi g(0)-1/2}-\delta_{\pi g(0)+1/2}$, which is equivalent to $g=c+\mathbb1_{[\pi g(0)-1/2\ ,\ \pi g(0)-1/2]}$ for some $c$ . If you chose $c$ such that $|c|>\frac1{2\pi}$, then $g=c+\mathbb1_{[c\pi-1/2\ ,\ c\pi-1/2]}$ is a solution.